# console.log not logging with await variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, binance

I am trying to log the data of a promise to my console but it's not showing. i have tried defining then in then and on top of functions and tried with let and redefining the before executing the algorithm but. no response

sample

```
var trade;
const getTrades = async () => {
    return await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: bUrl + tradeQuery
    })

}


const getSOrders = async () => {
    return await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: bUrl + mOrderQuery
    })

}
const postOrder = async() => {
  const binanceRest = new api.BinanceRest({
      ...
    }
  )

  binanceRest.newOrder({
      ...
    })
    .then(async(data) => {
      const trades = await getTrades()
      const mOrders = await getSOrders()
      console.log(data)
      console.log(trades)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
    })
}

(
    postOrder(),
    async () => {
        const trades = await getTrades()
        const mOrders = await getSOrders()
        const sells = mOrders.data.asks
        const buys = mOrders.data.bids

        while (true/*while order is in */) {

            trade = trades.data[trades.data.length - 1]
             console.log(sells)
           
        }
    }


)()
```

Comment: So to get the dumb question out of the way.  Are you ever calling `postOrder`?

Comment: Are you sure that `binanceRest.newOrder` is actually resolving the promise? Try console logging the promise object itself to see if it ever fills.

Comment: @Splox yes it is, the order is taking place, the issue is that everything in .then can be logged if   const trades = await getTrades()
      const mOrders = await getSOrders() are not defined

Comment: I edited the question, by the way the console.log in the while works

Comment: Please add a code snippet showing the problem

Comment: Hi @CamilleBasbous , I see in your comments to other answers that you did by purpose the infinite loop (that could be ok for testing purposes) but you also stated "the issue trades and mOrders are called before and should be logged before". That's not true because you are calling `postOrder` without `async` and because `binanceRest.newOrder` is treated as a Promise and not `await`ed: due to these two problems only the first two lines of `postOrder` are executed **for sure** before the first line of the anonymous async function, all the rest of your code is executed in an unpredictable sequence

Comment: Please @CamilleBasbous, try to fix the issues I wrote in my answer and you'll see a lot of problems will solve.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is stuck in a an infinite `while` loop. Since node is single threaded, it will continue to execute the loop until broken and never execute the `.then` code in the original promise.  You should be able to easily see this by commenting out the `while` loop.

Specifically:
`binanceRest.newOrder` is async call. It's true that `postOrder` is called first, but depending on the how nodejs decides to optimize, all of the `awaits` are hit at the same time. When the `awaits` resolve, if Nodejs decides that `postOrders` will resume your `console.log` will write, however if the `while` loop it hit first, then your program will be stuck there.

Comment: i made that by purpose but it ain't the issue trades and mOrders are called before and should be logged before

Comment: See my edit above. Test it out, you'll see that either: it works, or it doesn't work and you have still yet another problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to say this, but I can see a lot of confusing things in this code.

```
while(true) {
  trade = trades.data[trades.data.length - 1];
  console.log(sells);
}
```

this will never exits. If you omitted part of your code is not a good idea as this makes us harder to give you the actual answer to your question. If this is your real code, I would change in

```
while(trades.data.length) {
  trade = trades.data.pop();
  console.log(sells);
}
```

`postOrder` is an `async` function which deals with `Promise`, and this is confusing: I would rewrite it as

```
const postOrder = async() => {
  try {
    const binanceRest = new api.BinanceRest({ ... });

    const data = await binanceRest.newOrder({ ... });
    const trades = await getTrades()
    const mOrders = await getSOrders()
    console.log(data)
    console.log(trades)
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

Last `postOrder` is an `async` function which is called without `await` and this is source of confusion as well.

I would start cleaning your code, probably many problem will be solved as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't matter than it's called without an await, unless this code is running in a AWS lambda, nodejs will still wait for the event loop to be empty before shutting down the execution, which means it isn't the source of the issue.

Comment: It matters @WarrenParad & @CamilleBasbous . Due the flow never exits from that infinite loop, no other code block after `await`s which resolve later will never run.

Answer (score 2):

### Is not an "await" problem

I've added a bunch of `console.log` instructions at your code and there's no problem printing anything. Try adding the same to your original code, assuming your API's are working fine there's no reason for failure.

The following snippet mocks your API's, please take a look at the result. Your error must be at your logic, api's or syntax.

Also add a safe break inside your `while`, something like this: `if (calls++ > 5) { break; }`, to me it seems that the infinite loop is the problem.

```js
/* MOCK API'S */
let test = 0, calls = 0;
const fakePromise = (arg, apiName) => { return { then: (f1, f2) => { console.log('mocked result for ' + apiName); return f1(arg); } }; };
const axios = (args) => { console.log('-> axios is called', args); return fakePromise({data: { asks: ['ask'], bids: ['bid'], length: 1, 0: 'fake index'} }, args.url); };
const api = { BinanceRest: function(){ return { newOrder: () => fakePromise(' -> newOrder result <- ', 'newOrder')}; } };
const bUrl = 'bUrl/', mOrderQuery = 'mOrderQuery', tradeQuery = 'tradeQuery';


/* YOUR CODE STARTS HERE */
var trade;
const getTrades = async () => {
    console.log('-> getTrades is called');
    return await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: bUrl + tradeQuery
    });
}

const getSOrders = async () => {
    console.log('-> getSOrders is called');
    return await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: bUrl + mOrderQuery
    })

}

const postOrder = async() => {
  console.log('step 1');
  const binanceRest = new api.BinanceRest({
//      ...
  });

  console.log('step 2');
  binanceRest.newOrder({
//      ...
  })
    .then(async(data) => {
      console.log('step 3');
      const trades = await getTrades()
      const mOrders = await getSOrders()
      console.log('step 4.2');
      console.log('data: ', data)
      console.log('trades: ', trades)
      console.log('mOrders', mOrders)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
    })
}

// test
(
    postOrder(),
    async () => {
        console.log('step 4.1');
        const trades = await getTrades()
        const mOrders = await getSOrders()
        console.log('step 5', mOrders);
        const sells = mOrders.data.asks
        const buys = mOrders.data.bids
        console.log('step 5.0');

        while (true/*while order is in */) {

            console.log('step 5.' + (test++));
            trade = trades.data[trades.data.length - 1]
            console.log('sells: ', sells)
            if (calls++ > 5) {
              console.log('way too much calls, break! ');
              break;
            }
        }
    }
)()
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look at your `postOrder` func:

```
const postOrder = async() => {
  const binanceRest = new api.BinanceRest({ ... })

  binanceRest.newOrder({ ... })
    .then(...)
    .catch(...)
}
```

Now imagine the scenario when a typo has been made, f.e. it should be `new api.FinanceRest(...)` and as a result you end up with error:

> `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: api.BinanceRest is not a function`

Rest of code in `postOrder` is simply skipped, no `console.log`s. So the main point here: if in `new api.BinanceRest({ ... })` something leads to an error (any error) than you'll end up with situation you have right now.

And also worth to mention that an async anonymous function with `while` loop still gets executed and that's because `postOrder` is an `async` func  which means it returns a pending `Promise`.

Try running this in you browsers console to get more sense of what's goin' on:

```js
function delay(sec) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res("delay " + sec + "sec"), sec * 1000);
  });
}

async function getTrades() {
  return await delay(0.1);
};

async function getSOrders () {
  return await delay(0.2);
};

async function postOrder() {
  console.log("postOrder");

  const api = {};
  const binanceRest = api.BinanceRest()

  delay(0.4)
    .then(async (data) => {
      console.log("postOrder result")
      const trades = await getTrades()
      const mOrders = await getSOrders()
      console.log(trades)
      console.log(mOrders)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
};

(postOrder(),
async () => {
  const trades = await getTrades();
  const mOrders = await getSOrders();
  console.log("gfdfg");
})();
```